# Retirar uma parte do texto dentro de um arquivo txt

Tags: php

Colegas.

Tenho o seguinte código onde pego um arquivo csv através de upload e armazeno em um arquivo txt, do qual tem que ter a formação das posições conforme a base de dados de um programa. Para isso estou usando o código abaixo:

```
         $diretorio = 'arquivos/';
            $arquivo = $diretorio . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $arquivo)){

               $abrirArquivo = fopen($arquivo, "r");

              while(!feof($abrirArquivo)) {
                    $ler = fgets($abrirArquivo,460);
                    $campo1 = substr($ler, 0, 8);
                    $campo2 = substr($ler, 9,10);
                    $campo3 = substr($ler, 20, 10);
                    $campo4 = substr($ler, 31, 22);
                    $campo5 = substr($ler, 40, 10);

$leituraFinal = "
$campo1          $campo2   $campo3                          $campo4                     $campo5<br>";

                //$trocar = str_replace("<br>","",$leituraFinal);
                $trocar = preg_replace("<br>",null,$leituraFinal);
                file_put_contents($diretorio . "JAN_2012.txt",$leituraFinal,FILE_APPEND);
                file_get_contents($diretorio . "JAN_2012.txt");

            }
     }
}
```

Legal. Funciona, ao menos em partes, pois no arquivo txt aparece no final da linha o < br >.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se bem percebo pretendes substituir "null" por uma mudança de linha no ficheiro txt. Creio que para isso tens de fazeres o seguinte:

```
$trocar = preg_replace("\n", null, $leituraFinal);
```

Substituindo o código anterior:

```
$trocar = preg_replace("<br>",null,$leituraFinal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que você possa remover a tag `br` do final do arquivo txt, você poderia fazer da seguinte forma alterando o seguinte precho do seu código:

```
$trocar = preg_replace("<br>",null,$leituraFinal);
```

Para:

```
$trocar = preg_replace('/<br>$/', '', $leituraFinal);
```

Onde a expressão regular só irá remover o `br` que estiver no final do txt, mas caso você queira remover todos os `br` que possam vir a existir nesse arquivo txt faça dessa forma a alteração:

```
$trocar = preg_replace('/<br>/', '', $leituraFinal);
```